# Typescript not compiling correctly to commonjs/es2015

Tags: javascript, typescript, tsc, ts-node

I'm running Node v14.5.0. I'm using `ts-node-dev` in dev enviroment

Trying to compile to JS always gives an error.

At first, I tried with this `tsconfig`:

```
"target": "es5",
"module": "commonjs"
"outDir": "./dist",
"rootDir": "./src"
```

But when I run `tsc` and `node dist/app.js` I get the following error:

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: D:\Dev\src\entity\BaseEntity.ts:1
import {
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
```

After doing some research, I found that I should tell Node to use Modules adding `"type": "module"` to `package.json`. After that, the error changed to:

```
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
                      ^

ReferenceError: exports is not defined
```

Doing some more research I tried several different things like:

- Changing `tsconfig` from `"module": "commonjs"` to `"module": "es2015"`

  This also causes to be unable to run `ts-node-dev`. It throws the error: `Cannot use import statement outside a module`.
- Adding to `tsconfig` `"moduleResolution": "node"`

  With this and "es2015" module tsconfig I'm requered in all my typescript imports to use the .JS extension. Example: `import { foo } from '../bar.js`, otherwise throws an error like: `Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find module D:/...`. And of course, prevents me from using `ts-node-dev` as throws an error described above.

Comment: Try forcing the compiler to load the *tsconfig.json* with: **tsc --p ./tsconfig.json**. See [docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html). If it helps take a look at my project [here](https://github.com/carlocorradini/racer-server) and watch the *[package.json](https://github.com/carlocorradini/racer-server/blob/master/package.json)* and *[tsconfig.json](https://github.com/carlocorradini/racer-server/blob/master/tsconfig.json)*.

Comment: I don't think the problem is the TSC compiler not loading the tsconfig.json because the changes are being made in the compiled file.

Comment: Try *"target": "es2015"* and *"module": "commonjs"*.

Comment: With target "es2015" and module "commonjs" get the same error: "ReferenceError: exports is not defined"

Comment: Super strange. Try copying my tsconfig.json (see above) and use it as your primary config file. Maybe something is missing.

Comment: Same thing. My tsconfig was generated by tsc --init. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was in the `ormconfig.js` where my entities path was pointing to a `.ts` file instead of a `.js`.

Solution:

```
entities: ['dist/entity/*.js'],
migrations: ['dist/migration/**/*.js']
```